# For a straight line parallel to y-axis, using the formula $x = \frac{y-c}{m}$ gives $x = 0$

Tags: coordinate-systems

The general equation of a straight line is $y= mx + c$  but when a line is parallel to y-axis this equation doesn't work because the value of the slope is $1 \over 0$(taking 1 unit for rise and 0 for run), so I tried to solve it with respect to x so that the value of m gets inversed that is $0 \over 1$ which can be used to solve it.
$$\implies x=\frac{y-c}{m}$$
for a line parallel to y-axis the slope is $m={1\over0}$, substituting m in the above equation we get
\begin{align}x=(y-c)\div m \\ \implies x = (y-c) \div {1\over0}\\ \implies x=(y-c)\times{0\over1} \\ \implies x=0\end{align}
But $x = 0$ means that the line is overlapping y-axis and the correct answer should be $x = c$ where c is x-intercept. Where did I went wrong? and why can't we use this equation for this condition?

Comment: notice $\frac{1}{0}$ doesn't make sense as you can't divide by $0$. In this case there is no slope and the line is parallel to the $y$ axes.

Comment: The general equation of a straight line is $y=mx+c$ *when that line is not vertical*. When the line is vertical, one cannot start from that equation and hope to derive anything useful.

Comment: @DavideTrono but ${1\over m}$ gives ${0\over 1}$ which I think it makes some sense. In this case the line is still parallel to y-axis but the formula comes out to be x=0 instead of x=c.

Comment: @GregMartin I know why this equation can not be used in vertical line, it's because we cannot divide a number by 0, but the line is still a straight line and there should be some connection with it and that's why I was trying to derive it.

Comment: @MiranFirdausi In mathematics, we don't operate with expressions that "make some sense". Mathematics is a rigorous discipline. Just because a conclusion to an absurd argument is correct, that does not make the argument valid.

Comment: A way to describe such a line would be to consider the following subset of the plane: 
$$L_{x_0}=\{(x_0,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:y\in\mathbb{R}\}$$ for some fixed $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$. You could then make paths along this line instead.

Comment: @CSquared I agree with this, It basically means that the value of x is a fixed constant, and whatever we put in the value of y, x will remain same. I was just curious why this equation is not applicable in this condition and was trying to relate with it.

Comment: @MiranFirdausi: you might be interested in learning about "projective coordinates", in this case the "projective plane". Among other things, it does treat all lines on equal footing with one another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$m=\frac10$ is a nonsensical expression. As such, you should come as no surprise that anything you write **after** that expression will also not make any sense.

---

When the line is vertical, it's quite inaccurate to speak of it's slope as being equal to $\frac10$. It helps to be accurate when talking about mathematical terms, and to keep in mind what the definitions of what you are talking about are.

The definition of the slope of a line is that it is the value $k$ for which the equation $$y=kx + n$$ describes the line. In more detail, it's the value for which the set $$\{(x, y)| y=kx + n\}$$ is **equal** to the line.

If the line is vertical, it is relatively easy to show that **no** such value $k$ exists, and therefore, by the definition of the slope, the line **does not have a slope**. The slope is not equal to $\frac10$.

Comment: The slope of a line can be calculated using rise over run, in the case of a vertical line we can take any value of y suppose 1 unit but there is no inclination among x axis so the value of run is 0. that means $m = {1\over 0}$ and it is undefined or infinity. can you explain me why this line can not have a slope, it's just the ratio of height and distance of a line to show how steep a line is. In this case the ratio is 1/0 which is undefined. Btw I got the point we can not do operations with undefined.

Comment: The slope of a line can be calculated using rise over run **if** the line is not vertical. If the run is 0, then the slope **cannot** be calculated in such a way, because division by $0$ does not exist.

Comment: @MiranFirdausi "Undefined" is not a value. When we say that a number is undefined, we do not mean it is equal to undefined. We mean that the expression defining the number is invalid, and therefore, the number is **not defined**.

Comment: @MiranFirdausi If you define the slope of a line as "rise over run", then you literally did not define the slope of vertical lines. Based on your definition, i.e. "rise over run", the question "what is the slope of a vertical line" simply **does not have an answer". That doesn't mean there is anything wrong with the definition, it just means you are applying it to an area which doesn't make sense. All definitions are meant to be applied in a limited sense.

Comment: @MiranFirdausi For example, does it make sense to say "what is the weight of yellow?"? Of course not. Why? Because "weight" is a property of material objects, and "yellow" is not a material object. That doesn't mean the definition of "weight" is wrong, or that there is something wrong with "yellow". It simply means the question I posed does not have an answer. The answer is not *wrong*, it just doesn't exist.